# how to pass variables from Orbeon repeatable field to web service?

Tags: web-services, orbeon, xforms

i have a problem with passing variables from Orbeon repeatable field to web service

In HTTP Service editor:

Serialization: HTML form
Request body:

```
    <request><myvalue/></request>
```

in Actions Editor:

Source Control: myField
Destination XPath Expression: request/myvalue

It's working if myField is a single field, but how pass variables from repeatable field?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of Orbeon Forms 4.3, this is not possible. Form Builder actions don't yet support repeats. If you'd like to track this, you can follow [RFE #1105](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1105).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
maybe I can do some extra input field that will keep the values from repeatable fields with some separator?

I've made something like this:

```
        string-join(//myRepetableField, '/');
```

and i can separate it in web service. Maybe it is possible to build string "param1=value1&param2=value2.." using this idea, but i have to get an index of current field.

Answer (score 0):

Issue [#1105](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1105) is now fixed, and the fix will be in Orbeon Forms 4.5.